# Gstreamer doesn't recognize "ffdec_h264" (windows)

Tags: stream, streaming, video-streaming, gstreamer

I am running this pipeline on Ubuntu and it works fine.

But when I try to run it on windows, I get this error:

```
no element "ffdec_h264"
```

This is the pipeline:

```
gst-launch udpsrc uri=udp://172.0.0.1:5000 ! "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video,
clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! gstrtpjitterbuffer
latency=1000 , do-lost=true ! rtph264depay ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

I also tried to change from `ffdec_h264` to `avdec_h264` but windows doesn't recognizes it ether.

If someone know how to fix it, it will be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not that gstreamer does not recognize it. It is simply so that you don't have it installed. You can run gst-inspect to list the elements you have installed. If you would have told which version you installed and from which source, it would be easier to help.

Comment: If you start an new project I'd recommend to use gstreamer-1.0 (http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/).